# Are wood screws appropriate for subfloor with metal floor joists?

Tags: joists, subfloor

We recently purchased a new build and our upstairs floors are SO CREAKY.  It's only a matter of time before the tile floors crack due to flexing.  We pulled up some of the carpet in the bedrooms and found that they used wood screws to attach the subfloor to the metal joists.  Is this correct?  I feel like it isn't...

Comment: Are you sure they are wood screws?  Screws for metal look similar with some differences in the thread.  Metal 'joists' are new to me.  Would like to see a picture of them.

Comment: Metal joists?  You mean beams?

Comment: These sound like issues you should address with the builder. It's not acceptable in the 21st century.

Comment: @Huesmann, subfloor is attached primarily to joists. Steel joists may be common in other parts of the world. I'd also like clarity about that.

Comment: Can you tell how thick the sub floor is.  Most tile floors like about a solid inch or more thickness of the sub floor.  It is usual for tiles to crack on floors with less than an inch of sub floor.

Comment: OK, how can you tell that they used wood screws?  Did you remove one?

Comment: @Huesmann  Thinking about it, metal joists are common, it is just we notice them in industrial type buildings a lot more than in houses.  If done right are probably give a more flat level floor than wood joists.